# Using Docker Environment Variables in Angular2 application

Tags: angular, docker, webpack

I would like to use predefined Docker Environment variable inside 'environment.prod.ts' of Angular-Cli (1.0.0-beta.16).

usecase :

environment.prod.ts :

```
export const environment = {
production: true,
host1: $ENV1, //specific service endpoint goes here
host2: $ENV2 //specific service endpoint goes here
};
```

my Angular CLI based application depends on environment.prod.ts to fetch host information related to backend services (host1, host2) & application goes through various enviroments like DEV,TEST,QA,PROD ...

$ENV1 , $ENV2 are provided as environment variables during Docker run

is this possible ? If not,please correct my understanding & suggest any other alternative solutions

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this. I have exactly the same problem?

Comment: Nope ,using Resolver of  angular2 to prefetch the host information from  a configuration file

Answer (score 0):

Angular cli environments are compile time constants. This contradicts of course a bit how you think about an application when using Docker. With Docker you want to run the same artifact in different environments (using environment variables).

Until now I came up with two solutions, although both feel quite hacky to me:

### Use server side rendering

... and inject the variables into global scope. You can just append another `<script>` tag with the required variables after the opening `<html>` tag:

```
<script>
var environment = { 
  host1: 'some injected value', 
  host2: 'depending on the view engine you are using' 
};
</script>
```

and then have an interface

```
export interface Environment {
  host1: string;
  host2: string;
}

interface Window {
  environment: Environment;
}
```

### Use an API call

... to fetch the variables upon/after application start

You could do this in the `app.component.ts` in `onInit()` or have a [guard](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-guard) on your very first route.